# How to represent One-to-Many relationship in JSON using Php?

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have a MySQL table that has two columns 
customer_id and item_id,

customer_id can have multiple item_id, (One to many relationships),

How can I represent/loop through the returned query generate a JSON output (similar to the structure above) ,using MySQL and PHP?

for example, I want my JSON output to look like this:

```
  {
        "data": 
         {
            "customer_id": "10",
            "item_id": " 1"
          },
         {
           "customer_id": "10",
            "item_id": " 2"
         },
  {
           "customer_id": "10",
           "item_id": " 3"
         }
   }
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this. Here is a suggestion.

```
$data = [
    'Customer' => [
        'customer_id' => 29973,
    ],
    'Item' => [
        ['item_id' => 1 ],
        ['item_id' => 2 ],
        ['item_id' => 3 ]
    ]
];

echo json_encode($data) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
{
    "Customer": {
        "customer_id": 29973
    },
    "Item": [
        {
            "item_id": 1
        },
        {
            "item_id": 2
        },
        {
            "item_id": 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: this output does not match what the OP is asking for. But I would say it should be what the OP should go for (if he is able to change the part of the system that uses the outputted JSON)

Comment: On the one hand you are right that he *says* he wants the data as if it were the output of a join. However, comments indicate that he doesn't want the parent data repeated. I will leave this as a suggestion even though it doesn't directly match what OP asked for.

Comment: I do think this is a better solution for the problem (if he can change the part consuming the JSON), or he might even want this to be the solution, but did not write that in the question. Based on his comment, it would make sense, for him to change the question, and then this answer should be the correct one :)
my first thought after reading just the text was to go for a similar solution to yours, but then I saw the "desired output" and went with that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you will be getting the data from the MySQL.

```
$results = mysqli_query("SELECT customer_id, item_id FROM your_table_name");
$data = array();
while($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
     $data['data'][] = $result;
}

echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: This does not output information in a one-many manner as OP requested. Also, you are using mysql_ functions which have been obsolete for years.

Comment: the problem is the data gets repeated, i.e the unique customerid gets repeated

Comment: @ryantxr, you are correct about the mysql_query functions, replaced them with mysqli now, but i a real project it would make sense to use PDO anyway. But the output is exactly how the OP wrote what he wants

Comment: @CWilliams, if this is not the output you would want, you should update your question to reflect what you want. This answer provides the exact format that you ask for in your example